# Mysql select last row for each group

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT  
MAX('time'), c_id, message, state, time 
FROM message 
WHERE receive = 1 
GROUP BY c_id
```

I have a mysql query, I try to select the last row of each group, but it's not working.

c_id is the group. It select the first row of each group now.

Comment: can you show some sample data ?

Comment: Define "last row". Define "not working".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you should not escape the column name with single quote since it is not string literal. 
Second, you can do subquery which separately get the latest time for every `c_id` and join it back with the original table to get the other columns.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    message a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  c_id, MAX(time) time
            FROM    message
            GROUP   BY c_id
        ) b ON a.c_id = b.c_id AND
                a.time = b.time
```

or

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    message a
WHERE   a.time =
        (
            SELECT  MAX(time) time
            FROM    message b
            WHERE   a.c_id = b.c_id
        )
```

Comment: @Strawberry the second solution is from MySQL Docs. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: ...and so's the first, but the first is orders of magnitude faster!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  
MAX('time'), c_id, message, state, time 
FROM message 
WHERE receive = 1 
GROUP BY c_id
DESC LIMIT 1;
```

try to use this code

`DESC` start from the bottom of the table,

`LIMIT 1` select just one row (in the example will select the last row)

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to John Woo!

```
SELECT a.* FROM survey_question_option a INNER JOIN (
   SELECT    subordinate_question, MAX(sort) sort
   FROM      survey_question_option 
   WHERE     question_id=14
   GROUP BY  subordinate_question
) b ON ((a.subordinate_question = b.subordinate_question) OR (a.subordinate_question IS NULL AND b.subordinate_question IS NULL)) AND
a.sort = b.sort AND a.question_id=14;
```