# MySQL Pivot table with JOIN result has duplicate columns

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I'm having trouble creating a pivot table in MySQL using the following tables:

```
 Tasks 
   ----------
taskid | taskdesc  
1      | GenOP  
2      | Forks   
3      | Carpenter  
4      | Brickie  
5      | Digger  
6      | Plaster  
7      | Sparks  
8      | Trucks  
9      | Warehouse    
10     | CrewBoss   

 Clients
    -------
 clientid|clientname  
 1       | Client 1  
 2       | Client 2  
 3       | Client 3  
 4       | Client 4

Clienttaskrates
    --------------------
rateid|clientid|taskid|rate  
1     | 1      | 1    | 10       
2     | 1      | 2    | 12      
3     | 3      | 2    | 12    
4     | 3      | 3    | 14    
5     | 3      | 4    | 12    
6     | 4      | 4    | 18   
7     | 1      | 5    | 18    
8     | 2      | 1    | 13   
9     | 2      | 2    | 13   
10    | 2      | 3    | 13
```

I'm using this stored procedure to produce the table:

```
BEGIN  
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 32000;  
SET @sql = NULL;  
SELECT   
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  
         CONCAT(  
          'MAX(IF(rate = ',  
           rate,  
           ', rate, NULL)) AS ',  
           replace(taskdesc, ' ', '')  
     )  
    ) INTO @sql  
        from tasks pd JOIN clienttaskrates s ON pd.taskid=s.taskid;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT pt.clientname, ', @sql, ' from clienttaskrates                 s 
    left join clients pt
      on  s.clientid=pt.clientid 
    left join tasks pd
      on s.taskid = pd.taskid 
    group by pt.clientname');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    END
```

I'm getting an incorrect result and duplicate columns, as can be seen here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bba1/4
 There should only be column for each task and there appears to be values where there shouldn't be for some rows (Client 1 has '12' value for brickie and brickie appear twice).

I assume this is an issue with my JOINS but I have tried several different things to no avail. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/17830393/4104224

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply but I still can't seem to get it working. I am still getting duplicate columns. The problem appears to be that different clients have different rates for each task but don't necessarily have rates recorded for all tasks. I assume the issue is in the subquery

Comment: What should the output look like?